# Redmine RailsBaseURI

Tags: linux, redmine

I installed Redmine with this How-To
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_using_Debian_package

```
ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/redmine

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/redmine
echo "RailsBaseURI /redmine" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine
a2ensite redmine
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But I get following message restarting apache2.

```
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/redmine:
Invalid command 'RailsBaseURI', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

Best wishes

Comment: Can you show content of your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine`?

Comment: content: RailsBaseURI /redmine

Comment: Hmm, and is your `mod_passenger` also enabled? Try something in lines of `a2enmod passenger` or `a2enmod mod_passenger` (depends on your distro).

Comment: hm, same error again: Invalid command 'RailBaseURI', perhaps missspelled or defined..

Answer (score 17):

Partial solved with @favoretti 's advice:

```
#apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
#/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
Reloading web server config: apache2.
```

Means the errors are gone

Answer (score 6):

I arrived due to googling "Invalid command 'RailsBaseURI'.  There wasn't an answer for me here, but I later realized that this error was being caused by passenger not being enabled.

Assuming you have already installed it, you can enable passenger with `sudo a2enmod passenger`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check passenger configure.

1.whether link passenger.conf and passenger.load in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ls passenger.*
passenger.conf
passenger.load
```

2.check your configure files: passenger.conf/passenger.load

passenger.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /home/hao/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails4.0/gems/passenger-4.0.14
  PassengerDefaultRuby /home/hao/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails4.0/ruby
</IfModule>
```

passenger.load:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/hao/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails4.0/gems/passenger-4.0.14/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

3.whether passenger is runnig, according to [official doc](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#verify_passenger_running)

```
Restart your web server and run:
passenger-memory-stats
```